# Selecting nodes by attribute value

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XML like below:

```
    <TRANSFORMATION DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="RTR_LRC_RF_REFL_Unproc" OBJECTVERSION ="1" REUSABLE ="NO" TYPE ="Router" VERSIONNUMBER ="1">
              <GROUP DESCRIPTION ="" NAME ="INPUT" ORDER ="1" TYPE ="INPUT"/>
              <GROUP DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="EXP 1" NAME ="Good" ORDER ="2" TYPE ="OUTPUT"/>
              <GROUP DESCRIPTION ="Path for the data when none of the group conditions are satisfied." NAME ="DEFAULT1" ORDER ="3" TYPE ="OUTPUT/DEFAULT"/>
              <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" GROUP ="INPUT" NAME ="OWNER_HEORG_REFNO" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT" PRECISION ="10" SCALE ="0"/>
              <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" GROUP ="INPUT" NAME ="PATNT_REFNO" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT" PRECISION ="10" SCALE ="0"/>
              <TRANSFORMFIELD DATATYPE ="integer" DEFAULTVALUE ="" DESCRIPTION ="" GROUP ="INPUT" NAME ="REFRL_REFNO" PICTURETEXT ="" PORTTYPE ="INPUT" PRECISION ="10" SCALE ="0"/>
==============================================================================================
<GROUP DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="(Valid_Record_Flag = &apos;Y&apos; 
<GROUP DESCRIPTION ="Path for the data when none of the group condition
<GROUP DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="EXP2" .../> 
<GROUP DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="EXP3" .../> 
<GROUP DESCRIPTION ="" EXPRESSION ="EXP4" .../>
```

I use C# (LINQ to XML) to get some info from the abocve XML.

In the above XML, you can see the  node under .  You can also see that the EXPRESSION attribute for GROUP node occuring only once. I also have other sets of  nodes, where they also contain  nodes, but they have multiple EXPRESSION attributes (the nodes below the ===== divider).

My requirement is, I want to extract some info from GROUP Nodes having EXPRESSION attribute occuring only once.

I currently use the following C# code to extract the info:

```
 var q = from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("TRANSFORMATION")
                    where c.HasAttributes &&
                    c.Attribute("TYPE") != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Attribute("TYPE").Value) &&
                    c.Attribute("TYPE").Value.ToUpper().Equals("ROUTER")

                    select c.Descendants("TRANSFORMFIELD");
```

But this gives all TRANSFORMFIELD nodes including GROUP nodes having EXPRESSION attribute occuring only once.

How do I get TRANSFORMFIELD nodes where GROUP nodes having EXPRESSION attribute occuring more than once?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your requirements but I think you only want to get all `TRANSFORMFIELD` of the `TRANSFORMATION` that contains more than one `GROUP` element that has an `EXPRESSION` defined.  You could do this:

```
var query =
    from transform in doc.Descendants("TRANSFORMATION")
    where String.Equals((string)transform.Attribute("TYPE"), "router",
                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    // GROUP elements that have more than one EXPRESSIONs defined
    where transform.Elements("GROUP")
                   .Where(e => e.Attribute("EXPRESSION") != null)
                   .Skip(1).Any() // more than one
    select transform.Elements("TRANSFORMFIELD");
```